# Component was registered but is also waiting for dependencies

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, castle-windsor

I have some Castle Windsor component registrations that look like the following.

```
container.Register(
    Component.For<IService>()
        .Named("proxy-service")
        .ImplementedBy<ProxyService>()
        .DependsOn(Dependency.OnComponent(
            typeof(IHttpClient), "backend-http-client")),
    Component.For<IHttpClient>()
        .Named("backend-http-client")
        .ImplementedBy<DefaultHttpClient>()
        .DependsOn(Dependency.OnAppSettingsValue(
            "baseAddress", "backendServerBaseAddress"))
);
```

- `ProxyService` implements `IService` and has a constructor that takes a single `IHttpClient`.
- `DefaultHttpClient` implements `IHttpClient` and has a constructor that takes a single `string` named `baseAddress`.

Now if I try to test my registrations by calling `container.Resolve<IService>("proxy-service")` I get the following exception.

> Castle.MicroKernel.Handlers.HandlerException: Can't create component 'proxy-service' as it has dependencies to be satisfied.
>
> 'proxy-service' is waiting for the following dependencies:
>   - Component 'backend-http-client' (via override) which was registered but is also waiting for dependencies.

What's odd is that both of the following work.

1. `container.Resolve<IHttpClient>("backend-http-client")`
2. Switching the ordering of the `"proxy-service"` and `"backend-http-client"` registrations.

I'm really stumped here because I've used Castle Windsor a lot and have never encountered a problem like this that wasn't obviously caused by a typo or mistake in the registrations.

Why does (1) above work, but resolving the component that depends on solely it does not?

Why does (2) make it work? The order of registrations shouldn't matter unless there are multiple registrations for the same interface (which there aren't in my minimal reduced case). I have code for other projects that do the same kind of thing with many different registrations.

Is there something obviously wrong that I am missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem was that my little test was being run inside of the installer before it was installed.

My installer looked like this:

```
class WindsorInstaller : IWindsorInstaller
{
    void IWindsorInstaller.Install(IWindsorContainer container, IConfigurationStore store)
    {
        container.Register(...);

        //A little one-time test to try out the resolving of the service.
        //It would be removed as soon as it works.
        var service = container.Resolve<IService>("proxy-service");
    }
}
```

My application startup looked like this:

```
container = new WindsorContainer().Install(new WindsorInstaller());
```

So `Resolve` was being called before `Install`. Naturally, once I moved the test call to `Resolve` so that it would happen after the call to `Install`, everything just worked.

Answer (score 0):

In my case problem was that I registered `IService` but tried to resolve `Service` in constructor of top level dependency object:

```
public class MyController : Controller
{
    private readonly IService _service;

    public MyController(Service service) //problem here, Iservice should be used instead
    {
        _service = service;
    }
}
```